# Mutliple regression - single sparse feature

Tags: regression

Background: I have data obtained by sampling real-world, physical quantities. Say there are $10$ features. One of them, call it $x_1$, due to the nature of the sampling, is 0 most of the time. But when it is not 0, it can be very important.

So, how can I make sure $x_1$ gets treated fairly by the regression? Most of the time, $y$ will be determined by the other $x$s, but when $x_1$ triggers, it can be pretty important.

How can I fairly calculate $\beta1$ (for $x_1$)? Should I run a separate regression only on the samples where $x_1$ is significantly non-zero, take the residues, and then regress on the other variables? What's the best way to handle cases like this?

Comment: This question seems off-topic for CS.SE, but potentially suitable for [Stats.SE].  I'll migrate it over for you -- please check over there for answers or other feedback.

Comment: Why do would you treat $x_1$ any differently from any other $x_{i \neq 1}$? You can use weighted regression and weight the cases $x_1 \neq 0$ with a higher weight so these readings are treated as more informative but frankly do not see the reason fro this description. Do you have over-disperation problems or high leverage points?

Answer (score 0):

I agree, don't treat it differently rather use it as a weighted regression. You can check out http://www.statisticsconsultation.com/regression.html for more details on multiple regression and its output.

Comment: Can you flesh out your idea more?